# DjangoRestFramework - Where do I raise a 404 error when `get_queryset()` cannot get an object because it does not exist?

Tags: django-rest-framework

This is my view:

```
class PostListByUsername(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsLikeOrOwnerDeleteOrReadOnly, IsFromSameLocation,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        username = self.kwargs['username']
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        return Post.objects.filter(owner__username=username).order_by('-createdAt')
```

This is my `IsFromSameLocation` permission:

```
class IsFromSameLocation(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Permission.
    Allow permissions to authenticated users from the same
    location as the user.
    """
    message = 'Not from the same location.'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        username = view.kwargs.get('username', None)
        try:
            userProfile = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except:
            return False

        return request.user.userextended.location == userProfile.userextended.location
```

With that said, in my `get_queryset()` method, I do `user = User.objects.get(username=username)` but if the user does not exist, I want to raise a 404 error. I know that `get_queryset()` is supposed to return a queryset, so I'm guessing I shouldn't raise a 404 in that method. So where exactly should I do the check to see if the user exists or not? Note that in my permission, I do do a try and except to see if the user exists, but permissions should only return True or False from my understanding (not raise 404 errors).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually can raise an exception from a permission and it will be correctly handled by Django. For example you can do it with [`get_object_or_404()` shortcut function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404):

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    username = view.kwargs.get('username', None)
    userProfile = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    return request.user.userextended.location == userProfile.userextended.location
```

In fact, while the code that throws an exception is executed in a view, it will be handled by Django, so it should not matter where you are raising it from -- from view, serializer, permission, model etc. methods.

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot about this. Unless you have other code in your `try/except` block this is a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to [raise a `Http404` exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception):

In your `try/except` block, raise the 404 in the exception, but its probably worth limiting the exception to just [`DoesNotExist` errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist):

```
try:
    userProfile = User.objects.get(username=username)
except User.DoesNotExist:
    from django.http import Http404
    raise Http404("User does not exist")
```

Comment: Just to confirm, I do this in my permission or should I implement it in my get_queryset view?

Comment: @SilentDev you can do it in the `get_queryset`